# T-SQL - Perform LIKE if A in B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Below is a very simplified version of my statement

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE aColumn LIKE '01%' and aNotherColumn IN (1,2)
```

However, I only want to perform the `LIKE '01%'` WHERE `aNotherColumn = 1`

Is there a simple way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName 
WHERE (aColumn LIKE '01%' and aNotherColumn = 1) OR aNotherColumn = 2
```

Comment: Thanks - simple solution! Just wondering what would happen if there were lots of values. Would I just have lots of OR statements

Comment: @JanuszJasinski - hard to answer your question without seeing the requirements, but in essence yes.  Just be careful of mixing an AND in there WHERE X OR Y OR Z AND B is not the same as WHERE (X OR Y OR Z) AND B... (speaking from painful experience).

Comment: Note that as it sounds like you might be writing a very large where clause - easy to get that subtly wrong.  You may want to rethink how you are doing this, possibly introducing a temp table to join off...

Answer (score 0):

You can split conditions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE (aColumn LIKE '01%' and aNotherColumn=1) or aNotherColumn=2
```